# store awk output in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I ignore what is the problem with this code ?

```html
#! /bin/bash
File1=$1
for (( j=1; j<=3; j++ ))
{
    output=$(`awk -F; 'NR=='$j'{print $3}' "${File1}"`)
    echo ${output}
}
```

File1 looks like this :

```html
Char1;2;3;89
char2;9;6;66
char5;3;77;8
```

I want to extract on every line looped the field 3

so the result will be

```html
3
6
7
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes and escape the semicolon: `output=$(awk -F\; 'NR=='$j'{print $3}' "${File1}")`.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I cannot understand what do you want to do by reading your codes. you want to extract only first 3 lines? also why you need the shell for loop, if you have already used awk?

Comment: You have back-ticks *inside* `$( ... )`. That's just wrong. That will try to execute the thing returned from the inner back-ticks.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  YES but then it gaves me this log Error : 

./script.sh: line 8: NR==1{print $3}: command not found

do you have any idea?

Comment: You probably didn't copy and paste properly: you need to quote or escape the semicolon.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes exactly , the semicolon was the problem , just fixed it , thank man !!

Comment: Eh? The back-ticks inside `$( ... )` will never work... That's why you get the "command not found".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
File1=$1
for (( j=1; j<=3; j++ ))
{
                output=$(awk -F ';' 'NR=='$j' {print $3}' "${File1}")
                echo ${output}
}
```

It working well on my CentOS.

Comment: @technopathe **awk -F ';' '{print $3}' file** will do the same without for. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are mixing single quotes and backticks all over the place and not escaping them
2. You can't use bash variables in an awk script without using the `-v` flag
3. awk already works in a loop so there is no reason to loop the loop...

Just:

```
awk -F";" '{print $3}' "${file1}"
```

Will do exactly what your entire script is trying to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier, use the `cut` utility : `cut -d';' -f3` will produce the result you're looking for, where `-d` specifies the delimiter to use and `-f` the field/column you're looking for (1-indexed).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to extract a column out from a structured file like the one you have, use the `cut` utility.

`cut` will allow you to specify what the delimiter is in your data (`;`) and what column(s) you'd like to extract (column 3).

```
cut -d';' -f3 "$file1"
```

If you would like to loop over the result of this, use a `while` loop and `read` the values one by one:

```
cut -d';' -f3 "$file1" |
while read data; do
  echo "data is $data"
done
```

Would you want the values in a variable, do this

```
var=$( cut -d';' -f3 "$file1" | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

The `tr '\n' ' '` bit replaces newlines with spaces, so you would get `3 6 77` as a string.

To get them into an array:

```
declare -a var=( $( cut -d';' -f3 "$file1" ) )
```

(the `tr` is not needed here)

You may then access the values as `${var[0]}`, `${var[1]}` etc.